# Is there any efficient way to export data from remote DolphinDB server to local?

Tags: user-interface, dolphindb, export-csv

My DolphinDB GUI is connecting to a remote server and I want to export the data to my local computer. The function `saveText` can only save the file to the remote machine where the server is located. I have to transfer the file using `scp` command. Is there any efficient way to export the data to local?

Answer (score 1):

In the menu bar of DolphinDB GUI, select **Run**, then click **Export table**

[image]

Fill in the **Save Path** and SQL statement.

[image]

For example,

Fill “D:/test.csv” in the Save Path:

For a DFS table, the SQL statement can be:

```
select * from loadTable("dfs://test",`pt)
```

For an in-memory table, you should share the table first.

```
share t as st
```

Then export the table with the following SQL statement

```
select * from st
```